# How to find whether a ResultSet is empty or not in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

How can I find that the `ResultSet`, that I have got by querying a database, is empty or not?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Immediately after your execute statement you can have an if statement. For example

```
ResultSet rs = statement.execute();
if (!rs.next()){
//ResultSet is empty
}
```

Comment: however, if the result set is not empty, you will now have moved the cursor, effectively skipping the first row.

Comment: @Paul I believe you should update your answer to make it complete by resetting the cursor just before the first row in the else-block if it is not empty i.e. `else { rs.beforeFirst(); }`

Comment: That doesn't work with SQLite, @sactiw. It should be stated that if you want to use this approach, SQL driver needs to support other types than `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. SQLite doesn't support it. That means for SQLite, you need different approach.

Answer (score 33):

Definitely this gives good solution,

```java
ResultSet rs = stmt.execute("SQL QUERY");
// With the above statement you will not have a null ResultSet 'rs'.
// In case, if any exception occurs then next line of code won't execute.
// So, no problem if I won't check rs as null.

if (rs.next()) {
    do {
      // Logic to retrieve the data from the resultset.
      // eg: rs.getString("abc");
    } while(rs.next());
} else {
    // No data
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Do this using `rs.next()`:

```
while (rs.next())
{
    ...
}
```

If the result set is empty, the code inside the loop won't execute.

Comment: In case there is something to do if the result set is empty, then this doesn't do what you need. You'll need something similar to `while-else` statement, and closest match you can do is with @purush's answer with a `do-while` statement inside the `if-else` statement, where the `else` statement runs code in case the set is empty.

Answer (score 9):

If you use rs.next() you will move the cursor, than you should to move first()
why don't check using first() directly?

```
    public void fetchData(ResultSet res, JTable table) throws SQLException{     
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = res.getMetaData();
    int fieldsCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= fieldsCount; i++)
        ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addColumn(metaData.getColumnLabel(i));
    if (!res.first())
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "no data!");
    else
        do {
            Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= fieldsCount; i++)              
                v.addElement(res.getObject(i));         
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(v);
        } while (res.next());
        res.close();
}
```

Comment: I agree. I added my code below (could not include code with the comment).

Answer (score 5):

```
if (rs == null || !rs.first()) {
    //empty
} else {
    //not empty
}
```

Note that after this method call, if the resultset is not empty, it is at the beginning.

Comment: This way more safe, I thought.

Comment: ResultSet is never null.

Answer (score 4):

Calculates the size of the java.sql.ResultSet:

```
int size = 0;
if (rs != null) {
    rs.beforeFirst();
    rs.last();
    size = rs.getRow();
}
```

([Source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/305921/JDBC/java/find-size-my-resultSet#1386643))

Comment: As far as I know, that is a bad idea... first of all, you need to ensure that the result can move backwards, second of all, you take a performance hit when doing that. Much quicker to just use a forward only result set, and use a while loop (like has already been suggested by others here)

Comment: Agree... I voted up the accepted answer, which answers the question much more directly.

Comment: Dolph - NICE!!!!!